# How pull xcom value between task and taskgroup?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a requirement where I have to do xcom pull to fet few details from previous task.I tried many options but did not work in Airflow 2.2.3.
Here is a sample code example

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from datetime import datetime

def read_files_from_table():
    # Function to read the table and fetch the list of files to be processed
    files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.csv', 'file3.json', 'x_file.txt']
    return files

def process_file(file_path):
    # Function to process each file
    print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")
    # TODO: Add code to process the file

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1)
}

with DAG('process_files', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily') as dag:

    # Task 1: Read table and fetch list of files to be processed
    task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='read_files_from_table',
                           python_callable=read_files_from_table,
                           dag=dag)
    
    # Task 2: Process each file
    with TaskGroup('process_files_task_group') as task_group:
        # files = "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_files_from_table') }}"
        files = task1.output
        for file_path in files:
            if 'x_' not in file_path:
                task2 = PythonOperator(task_id=f'process_file_{file_path}',
                                      python_callable=process_file,
                                      op_kwargs={'file_path': file_path},
                                      provide_context=True,
                                      dag=dag)
                task_group.add(task2)

    # Define the task dependencies
    task1 >> task_group
```

Here read_files_from_table method is simple example i have given but its basically I read from sftp server and get list of files to be processed and based on that I have to loop the task for no of files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know little about this, so I could be wrong (hopefully I am), but according to [this document](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamic-tasks) the ability to dynamically create tasks (based on the Xcom value of a previous task, for instance) was introduced in Airflow 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to create dynamic Airflow tasks you should update Airflow to at least 2.3.0 version. Secondly, you should restructure your code as below. And one more suggestion: it's better to start using airflow decorators, it's a more declarative way to create tasks, task groups, etc. Read more about the concept of dynamic tasks [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) or [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamic-tasks)

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task, task_group


@task
def read_files_from_table():
    # Function to read the table and fetch the list of files to be processed
    files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.csv', 'file3.json', 'x_file.txt']
    return files


@task
def process_file(file_path):
    # Function to process each file
    print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")
    # TODO: Add code to process the file


default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1)
}

with DAG('process_files', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily') as dag:
    @task_group
    def process_files_task_group(file_path):
        process_file(file_path)
    # expand method is used for the creation of dynamic tasks
    process_files_task_group.expand(file_path=read_files_from_table())
```

You can see the DAG representation by following this link [DAG representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwgiZ.png)

Comment: Thank you I think I see issue in xcom dynamic task is working fine based on the structure I created as well.When I want it by xcom its not happening

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with **task decorators** to perform iteration over the previous task output. I have answered the solution for this exact use case [hhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479560/airflow-xcom-pull-in-taskgroup/78201205#78201205](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479560/airflow-xcom-pull-in-taskgroup/78201205#78201205)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35818158)

Comment: Also, if this is indeed an exact question duplicate, please use the flag option and link to your previous answer rather than reposting. Thanks.